# Public My Maps map: how make it easy for users to launch it in their Android Google Maps app?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps

I have made a My Maps map with some data and locations and made it public and embedded it on a site. How do I make it easy for users of the site to also access the map in their Google Maps app for Android (not the browser)?

Can I make a hyperlink on the site that launches the map in the Google Maps app?

Can I make a hyperlink on the site that adds the map to the users Google Maps as a shared map which the user then launches manually?

(After android asks the user for permission to do those things of course.)

Note that I'm not asking about how to [embed](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/4708605?hl=en) the map.

I also don't have a list of user emails to send map invitations to.

Update after comment by [ztan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299078/public-my-maps-map-how-make-it-easy-for-users-to-launch-it-in-their-android-goo#comment48713051_30299078):
The My Maps "Sharing" menu URL format is: `https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=[map id string]&usp=sharing`. In Android Chrome a click on that URL (hyperlink) shows me the "complete action using" dialog with only two choices: Chrome or default Android browser. Choice Chrome leads the user to My Maps web interface - not what I want!

But I found another URL format: `https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=[map id string]` That hyperlink in Android Chrome gives me a choice dialog that includes the Google Maps app. Good!

But a problem remains: on a second test phone the Chrome "complete action..." dialog didn't appear as the user had previously set some other map URL (AFAICT not a My Maps made map) to default to open in Chrome. To handle that case I could of course on a webpage inform users that if the link doesn't default to or provide a choice for Google Maps app then they can go to android application manager and "clear defaults" for Chrome and retry. Is there some *cleaner* way to ensure a browser hyperlink to a My Maps opens (or at least always gives the user a choice dialog to open) in Google Maps regardless of previous user "complete action using" default settings?

Comment: You can read more detail about how to share a map from [this documentation](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024935). If you have a hyperlink(url), you will have to launch Google Maps app thru your browser first.

Comment: The sharing menu in My Maps gives a URL with this format

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I've recently come across this very problem. How to make Android, from a web link, open your Google custom map in the Google maps app instead of in the web browser? I finally found how, you just have to use this URL format:

```
geo://maps/d/viewer?mid=[map_id_string]&usp=sharing
```